# How to create parent-child relationship in sql server2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

If i have two tables in my sql server 2005 and i need to create parent-child relationship between those tables so that i can retrieve that data using binding navigator in vb.net 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Add a primary key and foreign keys to the table which you want to relate as parent and child.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CHILD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PARENT__CHILD] 
FOREIGN KEY([ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PARENT] ([ID]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) relationship between the two tables.

Basically this is a column in one table that contains the id of a row in the other.

There are two ways to set this up.

1. The parent holds the id of the child. This is only useful if there is a 1:1 relationship between the two objects.
2. The child holds the id of the parent. This is more useful as there can be 1:many relationship between the parent and multiple children.

This example from the Wikipedia page illustrates the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier (
 SupplierNumber  INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Name            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 Address         VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 TYPE            VARCHAR(10),
 CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY(SupplierNumber),
 CONSTRAINT number_value CHECK (SupplierNumber > 0) )

CREATE TABLE Invoices (
 InvoiceNumber   INTEGER NOT NULL,
 SupplierNumber  INTEGER NOT NULL,
 Text            VARCHAR(4096),
 CONSTRAINT invoice_pk PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceNumber),
 CONSTRAINT inumber_value CHECK (InvoiceNumber > 0),
 CONSTRAINT supplier_fk FOREIGN KEY(SupplierNumber)
    REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierNumber)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT )
```